# nop commerce referencing images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am having trouble referencing a product image on my NopCommerce site.

i have changed the default slim box gallery to a booklet style gallery. i have managed to reference the 1st product image by inserting the code:

into the correct view. i now need to reference the 2nd product image on the 2nd page of my booklet.

so far i have:

added a definition in the catalog controller of:

```
model.PictureModel.Page2Url = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(productVariant.PictureId,  _mediaSettings.ProductVariantPictureSize, false);
```

I have also added this to the picture model:

```
public string Page2Url { get; set; }
```

after this i inserted this code:

```
Page2Url = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(pictures.FirstOrDefault(),     _mediaSettings.ProductDetailsPictureSize),
```

into the catalog controller under where the 1st image is referenced. this is now as the code says it should, referencing the 1st product image again. what do i need to change to get it to call the 2nd product image?

My site is:

Egiftingwizard.com

Comment: I think there is missing information or your question is not very clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try skip, take in linq to take the 2nd product image. Try this

Page2Url = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(pictures.Skip(1).Take(1),     _mediaSettings.ProductDetailsPictureSize)